# Twisties vs folders: how can I change the twistie icons in a JTree?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtree

If you look at this illustration at the top of [How to Use Trees](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)...

[image: JTree illustration from the Oracle JTree Tutorial]

... there are two kinds of icons.  I believe that `DefaultTreeCellRenderer.setIcon`, `setLeafIcon`, `setOpenIcon` and `setClosedIcon` affect the folders and big-black-dots in the illustration, but I'm interested in changing what shows up to the left of those.  How can I override the look and feel to change those?  Specifically, my look and feel doesn't use lines, and I want to put a small dot to the left of each leaf-node's icon.

This screenshot from my application shows how a sibling relationship between "Sub..." and "Expo..." is harder to see because the left margin doesn't line up visually.  Without looking carefully, "Sub..." can be mistaken for an aunt of "Expo..."

[image]

This OmniOutliner screenshot shows a possible solution to that problem, using small dots for leaves, that I'd like to try.

[image]

Comment: So what's wrong with using `setLeafIcon`?

Comment: `setLeafIcon` changes (for leaf nodes) the icon just next to the text label, as opposed to the twisties (or the lack thereof) on the left.  For instance, if I use `setLeafIcon` instead of `setIcon` in the code that generates my screenshot above, then the custom icons are replaced with "folders" (the look and feel default) except for leaf nodes which get their custom icons.

Comment: For a leaf node, there isn't any "decoration" available, it's normally occupied by the line. If you want to provide this, you need to make you're own look and feel delegate for `JTree`

Comment: Confirmation that there's no canned technique to set the decoration makes a pretty solid answer to my question, but I'm also not clear on what's entailed in setting up a LnF delegate for one kind of component.  (It didn't get clear to me here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html )   Could you say a little about how involved that is?  Can you build on the base LnF?